# How to print all links from the website in robot framwok

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

Thank you so much in advance for answering my question.
Below I tried to print all the links name in the console.
I could able to get no of count of links but could not able to print the name of the links.
Please help me to solve the query.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***


*** Test Cases ***

GetAllLInks
    open browser    https://tnreginet.gov.in/portal/       Firefox
    Maximize Browser Window
    ${nooflinks}=       Get Element Count    xpath://a

    Log To Console      ${nooflinks}


    @{linkItems}    create list

    FOR  ${i}    IN RANGE      1   ${nooflinks}+1
       ${linktext}=    get text    (xpath://a)$[i]
       lOG TO CONSOLE   ${linktext}
    END

*** Keywords ***
```

Below I am getting the error

```
Started: E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\rautomation\alllinks.robot
==============================================================================
Alllinks                                                                      
==============================================================================
[info] Opening browser 'Firefox' to base url 'https://tnreginet.gov.in/portal/'.
GetAllLInks                                                           175
[info (+7.14s)] ${nooflinks} = 175
[info] @{linkItems} = [ ]
[info (+0.07s)] </td></tr><tr><td colspan="3"><a href="selenium-screenshot-1.png"><img src="selenium-screenshot-1.png" width="800px"></a>
[FAIL] Element with locator '(xpath://a)$[i]' not found.
| FAIL |
Element with locator '(xpath://a)$[i]' not found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alllinks                                                              | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\log\output.xml
Log:     E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\log\log.html
Report:  E:\pycharm\projecttelegram\log\report.html

Robot Run Terminated (code: 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are just two minor typos in `get text    (xpath://a)$[i]`

1. move `xpath:` out of brackets. `(xpath:` -> `xpath:(`
2. index should like `$[i]` -> `[${i}]`

In total, the correct expression should be:

`get text   xpath:(//a)[${i}]`

Answer (score 1):

you could create the list by adding the links to get elements

```
${WebElements}=  Get WebElements  xpath://img
```

then you read out the attributes you want - I took the height and width of an image as an example, because our firewall won't let me out ...

```
${width}=    Get Element Attribute    ${element}    width
```

your code would look like this:

```
GetAllLInks
    Open Browser    url=${LOGIN URL}    browser=${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window
    
    ${WebElements}=       Get WebElements    xpath://img

    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{WebElements}
        ${width}=    Get Element Attribute    ${element}    width
        ${height}=    Get Element Attribute    ${element}    height
        Log To Console    Width: ${width}, Height: ${height}
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me with the answer.
I tried above code and it worked fine.

```
get text   xpath:(//a)[${i}]
```